# Como convertir un char a un tipo LPSTR en lenguaje C?

Tags: c

Mi ejercicio es una función que devuelve un `char`, pero el equipo fisico al que estoy programando me pide que sea un tipo `LPSTR`.

```
BOOL uart_Send(HANDLE hPort, LPSTR buf);
```

Estoy trabajando con comunicacion serial.

Answer (score 2):

Estás bien cerca de lo que quieres lograr. Según la documentación<sup>1</sup> de Microsoft, `LPSTR` es un puntero a `char` que puede estar terminado *(O no)* en `'\0'`.

Entonces, si tu función retorna `char`, sugeriría crear un array de 2 caracteres de la siguiente manera:

```
char toLPSTR[2] = { elRetornado, '\0' };
```

Donde `elRetornado` es el `char` retornado por tu función. Posteriomente haces un cast al tipo deseado:

```
LPSTR elString = (LPSTR)toLPSTR;
```

Con eso deberías poder llamar a tu función:

```
uart_Send(handle, elString);
```

De igual modo, esto funciona haciendo uso de `malloc` directamente sobre una variable de tipo `LPSTR`:

```
LPSTR elString = malloc(sizeof(CHAR) * 2);
*miString = elRetornado;
*(miString + 1) = 0; // Agrega el nullchar al final, por si acaso.
```

Y llamar a la función de la misma forma; si usas la segunda alternativa con `malloc`, no olvides hacer `free` al final del ciclo de vida de la variable.

> En todo caso, `LPSTR` es un `typedef` que expande a `char *`, así que con un `char *` no deberías tener problemas y te ahorras todo el problema. Una última alternativa que no recomiendo mucho es el hecho de poder pasar la dirección de la variable que guarda el caracter que retorna tu función de la siguiente forma: `uart_Send(handle, &elCharRetornado);`, con eso no deberias tener problemas igual.

Saludos :)

<sup>1: [Enlace a la documentación.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/3f6cc0e2-1303-4088-a26b-fb9582f29197)</sup>